# Processing - Null pointer exception on increasing in in for loop

Tags: nullpointerexception, int, processing

I am programming a video tracking program in Processing. 
Would anyone know why I receive a null pointer exception on increasing the int numberofblobs by 1. The initial value is two.

This is the whole code to provide some context. I've cleaned most irrelevant stuff.

```
int numberofblobs;

void setup()
{
  numberofblobs = 2;

  // Size of applet
  size(640, 480);

  // BlobDetection
  // img which will be sent to detection (a smaller copy of the cam frame);
  img = new PImage(80, 60); 
  theBlobDetection = new BlobDetection(img.width, img.height);
  theBlobDetection.setPosDiscrimination(false);
  theBlobDetection.setThreshold(0.9f); // will detect bright areas whose luminosity > 0.2f;
}

// ==================================================
// captureEvent()
// ==================================================
void captureEvent(Capture cam)
{
  cam.read();
  newFrame = true;
}

// ==================================================
// draw()
// ==================================================
void draw()
{
  if (!starttracking) {
    for (int i = 0; i<10; i++) {
      if (UNLOCKED[i])
        starttracking = true;
    }
  }
  if (newFrame)
  {
    newFrame=false;
    image(cam, 0, 0, width, height);
    img.copy(cam, 0, 0, cam.width, cam.height, 
    0, 0, img.width, img.height);
    theBlobDetection.computeBlobs(img.pixels);



    //if (starttracking) {

    locateBlobs();
    //}
  }

  println("numberofblobs:");
  println(numberofblobs);
}

// ==================================================
// locateBlobs()
// ==================================================
void locateBlobs()
{
  noFill();
  Blob b;
  for (int n=0; n<theBlobDetection.getBlobNb (); n++)
  {
    b=theBlobDetection.getBlob(n);

   if (n<numberofblobs) {
      println(n);
      vectors[n].x = b.xMin*width;
      vectors[n].y = b.yMin*height;
      println(n);
      // Blobs

      strokeWeight(1);
      stroke(255, 0, 0);
      ellipse(
      vectors[n].x, vectors[n].y, 80, 80 //b.xMin*width-(b.w*width),b.yMin*height-(b.h*height),30,30
      );
    }
  }
}


void keyPressed() {
  if (key =='1') {
    if (!UNLOCKED[0]) {
      numberofblobs++;
    }
    UNLOCKED[0]=true;
  } else if (key =='2') {
    if (!UNLOCKED[1]) {
      numberofblobs++;
    }

}
}
```

This line is highlighted by Processing upon throwing the error (in `LocateBlobs()`):

```
vectors[n].x = b.xMin*width;
```

---

On trying to narrow things down further I get the null pointer exception immediately, without increasing the numberofblobs int. 
The highlighted line is still the same.

This is the further simplified code:

```
int numberofblobs;
PVector[] vectors = new PVector[10];

void setup()
{
  numberofblobs = 2; // max 10

  // Size of applet
  size(640, 480);
}

void draw()
{
  println("numberofblobs:"); println(numberofblobs);
  locateBlobs();
}

void locateBlobs()
{
  noFill();
  for (int n=0; n<10; n++)
  {
   // b=theBlobDetection.getBlob(n);
    int i = n;
   if (n<numberofblobs) {
      println(n);
      vectors[n].x = 10;
      vectors[n].y = 10;

      strokeWeight(1);
      stroke(255, 0, 0);
      //ellipse(
      //vectors[n].x, vectors[n].y, 80, 80);
    }
  }
}

void keyPressed() {
  if (key =='1') {
      numberofblobs++;
  }
}
```

Comment: where do you define numberofblobs?

Comment: I defined it in the setup

Comment: could you add in how you declare it for some context, this seems like a scope issue

Comment: I have added a cleaned up version of my whole program. I hope this helps

Comment: You have two separate code blocks listed for `void locateBlobs()` which are not identical, which one are you using?

Comment: It has changed slightly because I'm experimenting meanwhile. The void locateBlobs() in the whole program code is the one I am using right now. Both versions give the Null Pointer exception at the same point.

Comment: On trying to narrow things down further by getting rid of irrelevant code, I get the null pointer exception immediately. (without increasing the numberofblobs int)
The highlighted error line is still the same.
I have added this further simplified code to my question post.

Answer (score 0):

In the code showed you creates no `PVector`. Unless they are created somewhere else, this is probably what gets you the NPE.

PVector is an object, you need to create them before accessing their fields.

in:

```
PVector[] vectors = new PVector[10];
```

You create the array of type PVector holding ten `null` "objects". But no PVector at all.

You should probably do

```
for(int i = 0; i< vectors.length; i++){
    vectors[i] = new PVector();
   }
```

yet in setup.

Then you will be able to later do:

```
vectors[n].x = 10;
```

Alternatively you could create them in locateBlobs func, like:

```
   if (n<numberofblobs) {
      vectors[n] = new PVector(10,10);
    // blah :)

   }
```

note: **ALL CODE UNTESTED**

hth

Comment: Actually this part was there but I accidentely deleted it, while trying to simplify my code. This is off course why I got the error immediately after simplifying. 
Your answer however, got me looking to the for loop where the vectors are created. This helped me solve it, hence the answer underneath.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the previous answer I found the problem.

In the for loop, creating my Pvectors I used numberofblobs as a constraint. This way too little vectors are available if the numberofblobs increases.

so initially:

```
for(int i = 0; i< numberofblobs; i++){
    vectors[i] = new PVector();
   }
```

should be

```
for(int i = 0; i< maxnumberofblobs; i++){
    vectors[i] = new PVector();
   }
```